# adding a ScrollPane in a GridLayout doesn't resizes the JTextarea in a JPane when changing size of JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jtextarea

I want to add a grid to the current GridLayout with a filled JTextArea component.
It works fine, but as mentioned in the title the JTextArea won't resizes itself 
after changing the size of frame.

I have already localized the error:

```
text.setLineWrap(true); //<--- here is the problem!!enter code here
```

in the method createGui.

Here is my Code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;
class GridLayoutExample {

    private JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    private JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    private JScrollPane pane;
    final JTextArea text = new JTextArea("Click me!\nClick me!\nClick me!\nClick me!\nClick me!");

    GridLayoutExample() { createGui(); } //constrcutor

    private JPanel createGui () {
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 2,0,0));          
        panel.add( new JLabel("Hello"));        
        //set style of first row, second column
        text.setLineWrap(true); //<--- here is the problem!!
        text.setEditable(true);
        //enable mouse listening and allow mouse action 
        doMouseActions();
        panel.add(text);
        return panel;
    }

    void addNewRow() {
        panel.add(new JLabel("Test1"));
        panel.add(new JTextField("Test"));
    }//addNewRow

    void showFrame() {
        pane = new JScrollPane(panel);
        frame.add(pane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }//showframe

    void doMouseActions() {
        text.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {

            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
                addNewRow();
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
                text.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);               
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
                text.setBackground(Color.WHITE);                
            }

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {}

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {}           
        });
    } // end of mouse action    

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GridLayoutExample test = new GridLayoutExample();
        test.showFrame();
    }// end of main
}// class GridLayoutExampleenter code here
```

On the one hand It works fine when I disable line wrapping, on the other hand I need
it to get the line breaks.

So any suggestions to do it better?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You are adding components at run time. In such cases you need to ensure the container gets revalidated:

```
void addNewRow() {
    panel.add(new JLabel("Test1"));
    panel.add(new JTextField("Test"));
    panel.revalidate();
    panel.repaint();
}//addNewRow
```

Also, you should create and access swing components only in the event dispatch thread. See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) for more.

Comment: thank you for the note. But the gridLayout still doesn't resizes itself once I've change the frame size.

Comment: @user3300710 What do you mean by not resizing? `GridLayout` makes all the components the same size. That includes the `JTextArea`.

Comment: ok, make the window bigger, you'll see that every component adjusts its own size. Than make it smaller, you'll see that the components don't change their sizes any more. The resizing after narrowing the frame won't work

Comment: @user3300710 OK. I'm not sure what you want from the line wrapping. In the example it makes no difference as making the window smaller will only bring up the scroll bars. However, in certain situations `JTextPane` line wrapping is more suitable.